# How to remove the same class from multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, navigation, single-page-application

Is there a way to remove the same div class from two separate divs?

I have a one-page application and I'm trying to get two of my divs that live in the same tab to hide after you click the other nav button. currently only one hides after you click to the next page. I attempted to hide the class with a for loop like this.

```
         nav: function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();  
        let currentPage = ev.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-target');
        let curPage = document.getElementById(currentPage);
        if (curPage) { 
          var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".active");
          [].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
            el.classList.remove("active");
          });
          document.getElementById(currentPage).classList.add('active');
          history.pushState({}, currentPage, `#${currentPage}`);
          document.getElementById(currentPage).dispatchEvent(onePage.show);
        };
```

the .active class = display block. and .page = display none

here is the html in this section.

```
<div class="page active my-5 mx-5 card-container padding-table" 
</div>
```

and the other div that lives on the same view. both have some content in them but this should show the gist of it.

```
<!-- end of reportingSummary -->
<div class="active my-5 mx-5 card-container padding-table" id="reporting1"
  v-if="authenticatedUser && (hasReportedToday !== 'true')">
```

Comment: Are you asking how to remove multiple classes from an element, or how to remove the same class from multiple elements? Please update your title to make that more clear.

Comment: Why don't you use Vue Router?

Comment: Remove the same class from multiple elements

Comment: I am new to Vue. I'll look into vue Router. Thanks.